# Select the same columns from the same table from four databases on the same server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four different databases and in each of these a DB_Version table. 
I want to create a select statement to get database name, version and updateTime
and display only the latest update from each database. 
Please note I want to use this in my WindowsFormApplication program. 
The environment is SQL Server.

That's what I got so far. But It does not show what I want.

```
SELECT  DB_NAME(), Version, UpdateTime
FROM [DB_A].[dbo].[DatabaseVersion]
UNION ALL
SELECT DB_NAME(), Version, UpdateTime
FROM [DB_B].[dbo].[DatabaseVersion]
UNION ALL
SELECT DB_NAME(), Version, UpdateTime
FROM [DB_C.[dbo].[DatabaseVersion]
UNION ALL
SELECT DB_NAME(), Version, UpdateTime
FROM [DB_D].[dbo].[DatabaseVersion]
ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC
GO
```

Any hints or tips would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You mean "latest update from each database"?

Comment: That's right... the latest update from each DB

Comment: BTW, is this question really MySQL related? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use `TOP 1` with `ORDER BY` like this

```
SELECT dbname, Version, UpdateTime FROM(
    SELECT TOP 1  'DB_A' as dbname, Version, UpdateTime
    FROM [DB_A].[dbo].[DatabaseVersion]
    ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC)as tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT dbname, Version, UpdateTime FROM(
    SELECT TOP 1  'DB_B' as dbname, Version, UpdateTime
    FROM [DB_B].[dbo].[DatabaseVersion]
    ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC)as tbl2
UNION ALL
SELECT dbname, Version, UpdateTime FROM(
    SELECT TOP 1  'DB_C' as dbname, Version, UpdateTime
    FROM [DB_C].[dbo].[DatabaseVersion]
    ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC)as tbl3
UNION ALL
SELECT dbname, Version, UpdateTime FROM(
    SELECT TOP 1  'DB_D' as dbname, Version, UpdateTime
    FROM [DB_D].[dbo].[DatabaseVersion]
    ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC)as tbl4
GO
```

You cannot use `DB_NAME()` as it is based on the database in the connection string and not on the database in the 3 part naming convention

Answer (score 1):

To find latest entry from a table, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  DB_NAME(), Version, UpdateTime
FROM [DB_A].[dbo].[DatabaseVersion] d1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from [DB_A].[dbo].[DatabaseVersion] d2
                  where d2. UpdateTime > d1.UpdateTime)
UNION ALL etc.
```